# How to setup Cloudwatch SQL monitor?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a view on a PostgreSQL RDS instance that lists any ongoing deadlocks. Ideally, there are no deadlocks in the database, causing the view to show nothing, but on rare occasions, there are.

How would I setup an alarm in Cloudwatch to query this view and raise an alarm if any records return?

Answer (score 1):

I found the cool script on Github specifically for this:

[A Serverless MySQL RDS Data Collection script to push Custom Metrics to CloudWatch on AWS](https://github.com/AndrewFarley/serverless-cloudwatch-rds-custom-metrics)

---

Basically, there are 2 main possibilities to publish any custom metrics on CloudWatch:

- [Via API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html)

  You can run it on a schedule on EC2 instance ([AWS example](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-custom-metrics/)) or as a lambda function ([great manual with code examples](https://stackify.com/custom-metrics-aws-lambda/))
- With CloudWatch agent

  Here is the pretty example for [Monitor your Microsoft SQL Server using custom metrics with Amazon CloudWatch and AWS Systems Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/monitor-your-microsoft-sql-server-using-custom-metrics-with-amazon-cloudwatch-and-aws-systems-manager/).

---

After all, you should set up CloudWatch alarms with [Metric Math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) and relevant thresholds.

---

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to configure Amazon CloudWatch to look *inside* an Amazon RDS database.

You will need some code running *somewhere* that regularly runs a query on the database and sends a custom metric to Amazon CloudWatch.

For example, you could trigger an AWS Lambda function, or use `cron` on an Amazon EC2 instance to trigger a script.